# JQuery fade out problems? In Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys, attached below is my code, and then my CSS. They item fades in correctly, but wont seem to fade out.

```
<div id="click-22" class="defer-icon">
<script>


      $("#click-22").click(function () {
        $("#22").fadeIn("slow");
      });
      $("#set-22").click(function () {
        $("#22").fadeOut("slow");
      });


</script>

    <div id="22" class="defer-pop">

        <div id="set-22" style="background-color:red">Set</div>
        <div id="cancel-22">Cancel</div>


    </div>

</div>
```

Class for defer-pop:

```
.defer-pop{
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    position:relative;
    top:-80px;
    left:-90px;
    background-color:#fff;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0, rgb(212,212,212)),
        color-stop(0.62, rgb(245,245,245))
    );
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
        center bottom,
        rgb(212,212,212) 0%,
        rgb(245,245,245) 62%
    );
    display:none;
    width:200px;
    height:80px;
    font-size:10px;
     box-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ababab;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #ababab;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 0px #ababab;
}
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="click-22" class="defer-icon" style="background-color:#000">

    <div id="22" class="defer-pop">

        <div id="set-22" style="background-color:red">Set</div>
        <div id="cancel-22">Cancel</div>


    </div>

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#click-22").click(function () {
    $("#22").fadeIn("slow");
  });
  $("#set-22").click(function () {
    $("#22").fadeOut("slow");
  });
})
</script>
```

**Css** for my help

```
.defer-pop{
    width:200px;
    height:200px
}
```

Remember include jquery.js above  tag

and **tip-**

you should be writing your code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your logic here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because `set-22` is a child of `click-22` and the event handler for `click` on `click-22` is fired when `set-22` is clicked.  To confirm this, put logging or `alert` statements in both event handlers.  To stop this behavior, use [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/) which prevents all other event handlers from firing, or [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation) to prevent parent event handlers from firing in the child's event handler:

```
$("#click-22").click(function() {
    $("#22").fadeIn("slow");
});
$("#set-22").click(function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $("#22").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

`stopImmediatePropagation()` prevents the event from propagating up to parent elements, and prevents other event handlers from firing.  I tweaked your example and have it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/a4ffk/

**Other notes:**

- Don't use numbers as `id`s.  This violates the [W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) and can cause problems with your script in some browsers.